# Can I send btc to a totally offline wallet?

Tags: armory, coldstorage

I want to setup a totally offline armory wallet. is it possible to send btc to a totally offline pc? Is it also safe, I guess it must be synchronized with the whole network, right? And there is something else, armory gives a paper wallet with a long code, can I use this code with any other software, in case something happens to armory?

Answer (score 4):

Yes to both questions.

You only need a wallet connected to the internet to remove coins from your account, not to add new ones to it.

A paper wallet can be used with any bitcoin wallet application.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer...

Not all wallets have support for offline/paper wallets.

Mycelium has the best support for offline wallets because it allows you to spend directly from the private key of an offline wallet. Mycelium likely recognizes all the private key forms that Armory can produce.

The version of Armory you have would continue working even if updates were to end. Armory appears to be open-source on github.com; therefore, updates will not end as long as there is a need for an update.

Comment: Its true that not all wallets have direct support for paper wallets, but with every wallet there exists some way to import a paper wallet, even if that method is hand rolling a wallet.dat file and placing it in the source.